# Mysql data and convert

Tags: mysql

I have table that contain a string field with data.
The date is in this format: dd/mm/yyyy
I need to show the max date.
I try some thing but without success

Select max(to_date) from payment

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function:

```
SELECT MAX(STR_TO_DATE(to_date, '%d/%m%Y')) FROM payment;
```

Answer (score 0):

you must convert your string to a date,
because now you are doing the max over a string not a date

```
SELECT MAX(STR_TO_DATE(to_date, '%d/%m/%Y'))
FROM payment
```